# How to centralize exception-handling in spring-boot application with spring security?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-security

I'm setting up jwt authentication in my spring-boot application and I want to handle all exceptions in one place.

I know that exceptions from Controllers can be handled in `@ControllerAdvice`, 
for `FilterSecurityInterceptor` I can set `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and `AccessDeniedManager`, and for `AuthenticationFilters` I cans set `UnsuccessfulAuthentication` manager. But that seems like far too many places to handle exceptions.

So I want to make it more centralized.

I decided to simply rethrow all the exceptions, so that `Tomcat` redirects the request to `"/error"` and sets exception details as request attributes. `"/error"` is handled by Controller, that extracts the exception form the request and rethrows it, so exception goes directly to the exception handler.

At my authentication filters (I've got a couple of them) I do this in the constructor: `this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(
              ExceptionHandlerUtils::authenticationFailureHandler);`

```
public static void authenticationFailureHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
    throw authenticationException;
}
```

And the same for the FilterSecurityInterceptor (in security configuration):

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http
                .authenticationEntryPoint(ExceptionHandlerUtils::authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(ExceptionHandlerUtils::accessDeniedHandler);
        ...
    }
```

Then, because of unhandled exception (`filterChain` doesn't handle exceptions (except some `AuthenticatoinException`, etc), request processing rolls back to the `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve`, that finally catches it, does this:

```
try { 
      *shortly, filterChain.doFilter(...)*
    } catch (Throwable e) {
            ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(e);
            container.getLogger().error(sm.getString(
                    "standardWrapper.serviceException", wrapper.getName(),
                    context.getName()), e);
            throwable = e;
            exception(request, response, e);
        }
```

Here happens unwanted logging, and `exception(...)` method sets exception as request attribute, then `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve#throwable(...)` sets some other request attributes and redirects the request to "/error". Than request goes through chain again to my `RethrowingErrorController`

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
    public Object getError(HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable {
        Object val = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
        if (val != null) {
            throw (Throwable) val;
        }

        /* this should never be called, but whatever */
        return "why are you here???";
    }
```

And finally is handled by

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Log4j2
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleUnexpectedException(
            RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        log.error("unexpected conflict:", ex);
        Map<?, ?> body = ExceptionHandlerUtils.getErrorAttributes(request, false);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, body, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }

}
```

This approach allows me to handle all exceptions that happen in any `Controller` or `Filter` (like JwtAuthorizationFilter) in `SpringSecurityFilterChain` in one place.

However, before tomcat redirects request to "/error" as described above, it complains about "internal error" (my exception) in logs.  I don't want that in logs, because I log errors in `@ControllerAdvice` anyway, and also I don't want to disable tomcat logs completely.

I can disable logs from the whole `package org.apache.catalina.core;` in `application.yml`

```
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.catalina.core: off
```

But I am worried, that I might miss something important later. So, I need either a better solution for centralizing exceptions, or a solid way to hide unwanted error logs.

All suggestions to improve my question are very welcome!